# Why does the string output from Arduino look like alien text?

Tags: string, matlab, arduino, serial-communication

I'm trying to set up a serial communication between Arduino and MATLAB over USB. I have this basic code where I'm sending "hello" from MATLAB to Arduino, and I read it back and print it in MATLAB. However, the "hello" sent from Arduino looks like a strange text.

Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial.println("ready");
}

void loop() {
  String input;
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char c = Serial.read();    
    while (c != '\n') {
      input += c;
      c = Serial.read();
    }
    Serial.println("I received: " + String(input));
    input = "";
  }
}
```

MATLAB:

```
s = serial('COM3');
set(s, 'BaudRate', 57600);
fopen(s);
pause(1);

first = strtrim(convertCharsToStrings(fgetl(s)));
if first == "ready"
    fprintf(s, '%s', 'hello\n');
    for i = 1:10
        tline = strtrim(convertCharsToStrings(fgetl(s)));
        disp(tline);
        if size(tline, 2) > 0
            fprintf(s, '%s', 'hello\n');
        end
    end
end

fclose(s);
```

The output in MATLAB looks like this:

```
I received: hÿÿÿÿÿÿeÿÿÿÿÿÿÿlÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿlÿÿÿÿÿÿoÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

Also, I would appreciate any constructive criticism on improving my code for serial communication. This is my first time, and I'm trying to get a simple setup in which Arduino and MATLAB take turns writing and reading. Thank you.

Comment: From the MATLAB side, try `fprintf(s, '%s\n', 'hello');` (notice how the `\n` character in in the _format string_ rather than the _message string_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your microcontroller code reads faster than you're physically sending characters, so you're reading from an empty buffer. `Serial.available()` has one char for you, you read it, then you read more chars even though the receive buffer is already empty. `Serial.read()` will return `-1` when there's nothing to read. `-1` cast to `char` is `0xFF`, or in Ascii `'ÿ'`.

You could change `loop()` to something like

```
void loop() {
  String input;
  while (Serial.available()) {
    char c = Serial.read();    
    if (c != '\n') {
      input += c;
    } else {
      Serial.println("I received: " + String(input));
      input = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Or you could go with Arduino's `Serial.readString()`:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial.setTimeout(20);
  Serial.println("ready");
}
void loop() {
  String input = Serial.readString();
  Serial.println("I received: " + input);
}
```

Both untested, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it was. I'm still not familiar with different data/text types, so I didn't know where that strange 'y' character came from. Thank you for explaining.